# Динамическое добавление компонентов react react-pixi

Tags: reactjs, pixijs

Использую [react-pixi](https://reactpixi.org/), столкнулся с проблемой динамического обновления компонента **Stage**.

Цель: добавление и удаление компонетов на клик по кнопке.

Текущий код:

*src/app/main.js*

```
**imports**

export class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.stage = React.createRef();
    ...
}
addComponent(){
    //How can i do this?
}
**other methods**
render() {
  return (
    <Stage
      width={this.w}
      height={this.h}
      options={{ autoDensity: true, backgroundColor: this.c }}
      ref={this.stage}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    >
      <Container>
        <SomeObject tint={0x00ffff} x={150} y={100} />
      </Container>
    </Stage>
 
   );
}
```

*src/pages/page.js*

```
import { Canvas } from "../app/main";

export const Page = () => {
    const canvas = React.createRef();
    ...
 
 return (
   <Layout>
      <Button onClick={function(){
         canvas.current.addComponent()
       }}/>
      <Canvas ref={canvas} />
   </Layout>

 }
```

Правильно ли я работаю с компонентами React и как я могу выполнить свою задачу?
Ps: на *CodePen* разработчика *react-pixi* есть пример mount-unmount node, но там он использует **PIXI.Application**, что в моем случае не действенно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция **render** из пакета **@inlet/react-pixi** принимает два аргумента:

1. компонент
2. экземпляр **PIXI.Container**

Последний можно найти либо в **PIXI.APPlication{stage}** либо при использовании *React.createRef* в **stage.current.app.stage**